# JS как добавить prototype функцию к NodeList

Tags: javascript

Сделал сокращенные функции querySelector и querySelectorAll

```
function get(s){
    return document.querySelector(s);
}

function getAll(s){
    return document.querySelectorAll(s);
}

NodeList.prototype.get=function(s){
    return this.querySelector(s)
}

NodeList.prototype.getAll=function(s){
    return this.querySelectorAll(s)
}
```

применяю:

```
el=getAll("#dbdata tr")[r].getAll("td")[c].get(".cell")
```

консоль говорит `.getAll is not a function`
решение?

Comment: ты добавил функцию в NodeList, а вызвать ее пытаешься у Node

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы записали функцию в прототип NodeList, и обращаетесь не к списку элементов, а к конкретному элементу. 
Попробуйте записать функции в прототип объекта Node